# CRUD Swing - Request Insert Into

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I would like to create a CRUD system through a From .There are 4 fields in my table : CodeA, TitreA, SortieA, IdentA (foreign key) .The last field in the form is a dropdown fiels and When I enter values for all the fields and save the form, there occurs a problem.

Here is a preview:

https://zupimages.net/up/18/21/uxwa.png

I guess the problem is about syntax:

```
public boolean insertAlbum (Album alb)
    {

        boolean ok = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().actionQuery("Insert into album (CodeA, TitreA, SortieA, IdentC) values ('" + alb.getCodeA() + "','" + alb.getTitreA() +
        "'," + alb.getSortieA() + "," + alb.getCatApp().getIdentC());

        return ok;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The `values (` part of your query is not closed .

Comment: You should implement `public String toString()` method for the class which instances are in the combobox.

Comment: You should use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid syntax errors (if title contains an apostrophe), or SQL injection bugs.

Comment: @Berger; thank you for your help I edit my requet but it's still not good... boolean ok = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().actionQuery("Insert into album (CodeA, TitreA, SortieA, IdentC) values ('" + alb.getCodeA() + "','" + alb.getTitreA() +
        "'," + alb.getSortieA() + "," + alb.getCatApp().getIdentC() + ")");

Comment: @– Sergiy Medvynskyy ; OK but do you have an example?

Comment: @julliiie net has plenty of examples. How we can give You example, when You not show class code?

Comment: Upload your image to the forum, not an external website.

Comment: Avoid SQL Injection -- use a **PreparedStatement**.

Comment: @ Jacek Cz; here is my errors messages ;-( https://zupimages.net/up/18/21/sy5z.png